# Is the IEEE_UNDERFLOW_FLAG pausing my fortran code?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

My fortran code is pausing at random points and I'm wondering if it is related to the flags IEEE_UNDERFLOW_FLAG IEEE_DENORMAL. I understand these are not very bad exceptions. I get the messages:

> PAUSE  To resume execution, type go.  Other input will terminate the
>   job.  Note: The following floating-point exceptions are signalling:
>   IEEE_UNDERFLOW_FLAG IEEE_DENORMAL

Is there a way to tell gfortran to ignore these exceptions if they are in fact the cause?

Comment: A casual inspection of your code and the options you used suggest "maybe".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unlikely that these exceptions are pausing your code, although without seeing any of your code it's impossible to tell.

It's more likely that your code contains the [`pause` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/6j4m0vnal/index.html), and that the compiler takes the opportunity of being paused to tell you that `IEEE_UNDERFLOW_FLAG` and `IEEE_DENORMAL` have been trapped.

If you still want to disable these exceptions, take a look at gfortran's  [debugging options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Debugging-Options.html). `ffpe-summary=` controls which exceptions are printed (which is likely happening in your case), and `ffpe-trap=` controls which exceptions cause your program to terminate (which is likely not happening in your case).

Comment: Wrong option.  See the documentation for -ffpe-summary.  You can suppress notification of specific IEEE exceptions flags, or all of them.  -ffpe-summary=none.

Comment: Ah, yes, good spot. I've edited my answer accordingly.